# python regex for extracting number in string

Tags: python, regex

My string is this:

```
<tr id="xyz21" style="" class="standard">
```

When I run my regex through the online regex helper site, pythex.org, I get what I'm wanting; only the number "21". The site says:

Match captures "21"

Here's the regex I used:

```
<tr id="xyz(.*?)"
```

However, when I use this same regex in my Python 3 script, I get much more. Here's the script with the result:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '<tr id="xyz21" style="" class="standard">'
>>> num = re.search('<tr id="xyz(.*?)"', x).group()
>>> print(num)
<tr id="xyz21"
```

Ultimately, all I want is to create a variable with a value of "21". By the way, the actual string I use the regex on is a lot longer than what I'm showing. It's a small file, actually. I've simplified my example just to make it easier to understand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter:

```
re.search('<tr id="xyz(.*?)"', x).group(1)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) noted that

> If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there
>   are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per
>   argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match
>   is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return
>   value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range
>   [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized
>   group.